# Primefaces How to show/hide inputText based on selected selectManyCheckbox items

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need your assistance in showing and hiding `inputText` based on the selected items in the `selectManyCheckbox`in the xhtml. The code is:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="basic" value="#{user1.selectedConsoles}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One SS" itemValue="XboxOne" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4 SS" itemValue="PS4" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii U SS" itemValue="WiiU" />
  <p:ajax listener="#{user1.renderInput}" update="name"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>

 <h:panelGroup id="name">
  <p:inputText value="" rendered="#{user1.renderText}"/>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

And the bean code:

```
private String[] selectedConsoles; //Setter & Getter
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //Setter & Getter
private boolean renderText = false; //Setter & Getter


public void renderInput() {
  list= Arrays.asList(selectedConsoles);
  if (list.contains("PS4")) {
    renderText = true;
  }
  else if (!list.contains("PS4")) {
        renderText = false;
  }
}
```

If the `selectManyCheckbox` contains ("PS4"), then show the inputText, otherwise keep it hidden. Now in the above case, it is showing if I have selected `PS4`, but when I unckeck `PS4`, the inputText will remain in the form and will not be hidden.

Comment: @Kukeltje The first part is similar, however for the second part it is different

Comment: Yes, but there should only be one question per question. So it still is a duplicate. file a new question for the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead - the `inputText` is not visible at the start, so it cannot be updated.

```
 <h:panelGroup id="name">
      <p:inputText value="" rendered="#{user1.renderText}"/>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Still it is the same, the inputText is not shown

Comment: Please ignore the above comment. Thanks it works, however  one more quetion if I uncheck it again, the inputText should be hidden again. I tried to do an else if and added !(list.contains("PS4")) but the inputText is not hidden and it is still shown

Comment: Can you update your question with what you've added?

Comment: the update in the code is in the if statement part only

Comment: Could you please assist on how to show the inputText by unchecking the "PS4". It seems that the method in the ajax is called only once

Comment: File a new question for the new question…